# Resizing video in AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I am trying to merge multiple videos in one. Every video may have different dimensions and the resulting composition size may be changed by user. Here is my function which creates an instruction for each of the videos being merged.

```
func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(assetTrack: AVCompositionTrack, videoSize: CGSize) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: assetTrack)

    let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
    let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform: transform)

    var scaleToFitRatio: CGFloat
    var moveTransform: CGAffineTransform
    if assetTrack.naturalSize.height/videoSize.height > assetTrack.naturalSize.width/videoSize.width {
        scaleToFitRatio = videoSize.height / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
        let xMoveFactor = (videoSize.width - assetTrack.naturalSize.width * scaleToFitRatio) / 2
        moveTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xMoveFactor, y: 0)
    } else {
        scaleToFitRatio = videoSize.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
        let yMoveFactor = (videoSize.height - assetTrack.naturalSize.height * scaleToFitRatio) / 2
        moveTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: yMoveFactor)
    }

    let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
    var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor).concatenating(moveTransform)
    if assetInfo.orientation == .down {
        let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + videoSize.height
        let centerFix = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: assetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: yFix)
        concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(centerFix).concatenating(scaleFactor).concatenating(moveTransform)
    }
    instruction.setTransform(concat, at: kCMTimeZero)

    return instruction
}
```

My problem is that extra lines of random color appear sometimes at the edges of my resulting composition.
[image with lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4RJX.png)
 I've seen an answer saying that the reason to that is that the size of resulting composition must be devisible by 16 (or at least 2).
So here goes my question. How can I make sure that after applying the matrix

`let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)`

the result will be even integer, moreover divisible by anything?

Sorry if I didn't provide enough information, and thanks to everybody taking time to try and help

Comment: Hey man!, Im trying to do exactly that, but Im still learning how to use layerInstructions. Im confused whether I should create multiple AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction and assing them to a AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction OR make multiple AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction with only 1 layerInstruction per video. Can you share your code just to see how that works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "sometimes" is likely when the scaled video's height ends up as an odd number of pixels, which then when centered exactly makes the edges on half-pixel boundaries. In that case, you simply need to floor the y origin of the video so it's at a full-pixel boundary.

Comment: Thank you so much, seems like it worked. I didn't realize the positioning of the video matters.